# Android : IllegalArgumentException: "Component class X does not exist" in API 17 (no crash in API 8)

Tags: android, illegalargumentexception, android-2.2-froyo

My emulators :

[image: emulators]

When I launch the tablet emulator I get :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Component class TriggerMonitoringBootReceiver does not exist in di.k23b.hw3
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1429)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1379)
    at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub$Proxy.setComponentEnabledSetting(IPackageManager.java:2561)
    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(ApplicationPackageManager.java:1250)
    at di.k23b.hw3.receivers.TriggerMonitoringBootReceiver.enable(TriggerMonitoringBootReceiver.java:81)
    at di.k23b.hw3.receivers.TriggerMonitoringBootReceiver.enable(TriggerMonitoringBootReceiver.java:86)
    at di.k23b.hw3.activities.SettingsActivity.onSharedPreferenceChanged(SettingsActivity.java:192)
    at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl$EditorImpl.notifyListeners(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:475)
    at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl$EditorImpl.apply(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:385)
    at android.preference.Preference.tryCommit(Preference.java:1349)
    at android.preference.Preference.persistBoolean(Preference.java:1615)
    at android.preference.TwoStatePreference.setChecked(TwoStatePreference.java:83)
    at android.preference.TwoStatePreference.onClick(TwoStatePreference.java:69)
    at android.preference.Preference.performClick(Preference.java:949)
    at android.preference.PreferenceScreen.onItemClick(PreferenceScreen.java:215)
    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1100)
    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2749)
    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3423)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

When I launch the froyo emulator all is fine (**EDIT** : no it is not - the receiver is not enabled BUT still ***there is no crash***).
Is it a known issue or something ?

Manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="di.k23b.hw3"
    android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="di.k23b.hw3.activities.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="di.k23b.hw3.activities.SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_settings" >
        </activity>
        <receiver
            android:name="di.k23b.hw3.receivers.TriggerMonitoringBootReceiver"
            android:enabled="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="di.k23b.hw3.receivers.BatteryMonitoringReceiver"
            android:enabled="false"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Relevant parts from the receiver (WIP !) :

```
private static void enable(Context context, boolean enable, String className) {
    PackageManager pacman = context.getPackageManager();
    final ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(context, className);
    final int state = (enable) ? PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED
            : PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED;
    pacman.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, state,  // line 81
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
}

public static void enable(Context baseContext, boolean enable) {
    enable(baseContext, enable,                 // line 86
            TriggerMonitoringBootReceiver.class.getSimpleName());
}
```

And in SettingsActivity:

```
@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sp, String key) {
    if (MASTER_ENABLE.equals(key)) {
        TriggerMonitoringBootReceiver.enable(getBaseContext(),        // line 192
                sp.getBoolean(key, false));
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "CB: " + sp.getBoolean(key, false), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }
}
```

---

***EDIT*** : all clear now, using `ComponentName(Context pkg, Class<?> cls)`- as for the difference in the APIs:

> Calls to `PackageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting` will now throw an `IllegalArgumentException` if the given component class name does not exist in the application's manifest. - [from the Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES#JELLY_BEAN)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TriggerMonitoringBootReceiver.class.getSimpleName();
```

and package

```
PackageManager pacman = context.getPackageManager();
```

which together give

```
di.k23b.hw3.TriggerMonitoringBootReceiver
```

so you are missing "/receivers/" folder prefix in class name

Comment: I get the context with `getBaseContext()` - tried with `getApplicationContext()` also to no avail - so my question is now : which `ComponentName()` [constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentName.html#ComponentName%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String%29) should I use ? How should I get the context if using the constructor I _did_ use ? And why API 17 crashes while API 8 not ?

Answer (score 1):

Just summarizing information already in this thread.
 Use the constructor
`ComponentName(Context pkg, Class<?> cls)`.
Also, the component name needs to be specified in the manifest. See JELLYBEAN in [this link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html).
 `Calls to PackageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting will now throw an IllegalArgumentException if the given component class name does not exist in the application's manifest.`

Comment: Do I need to provide the complete class path for component in the Manifest? I have specified .<component-name> in the manifest yet getting IllegalArgumentException.

Comment: @Ishaan "android:name=" should be the complete path I believe. I referred my code, and that's what I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [AndroidAnnotations](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations), use overridden class name instead.

```
// CORRECT class definition.
ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, NotificationPublisher_.class);
```

but,

```
// THIS WILL GIVE YOU CRASH.
ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, NotificationPublisher.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it may have worked but a piece of advice:
make sure your reciever is not disabled bro.

See, in you manifest it written as enabled="false", maybe, later day, it will cause you error.